# javafx - when I drag my stage too fast, mouse "anchor" change in the stage and the dragging is not correct

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, drag

I designed an undecorated stage and I want to move it around the screen clicking in the stage and dragging it.

My controller handles two event: mousePressendHandler and mouseDraggedHandler.

The first event is fired when the user click with the mouse on the stage. In this method I store the coordinates relatives to the stage of the mouse pointer.

The second event is fired when the user moves the mouse without relasing the button. Than I move the stage subtracting the coordinates of the mouse pointer in the screen and setting the result to the stage.

Examples:

```
 @FXML
public void mousePressedHandler(MouseEvent me) {
    dragAnchorX = me.getScreenX() - stage.getX();
    dragAnchorY = me.getScreenY() - stage.getY();
}

@FXML
public void mouseDraggedHandler(MouseEvent me) {
    double stageX = me.getScreenX() - dragAnchorX;
    double stageY = me.getScreenY() - dragAnchorY;

    stage.setX(stageX);
    stage.setY(stageY);
}
```

I want to avoid the stage to go out of the screen, so I modified the second method:

```
@FXML
public void mouseDraggedHandler(MouseEvent me) {
    double stageX = me.getScreenX() - dragAnchorX;
    if (stageX > 0) {
        stage.setX(stageX);
    }

    double stageY = me.getScreenY() - dragAnchorY;
    if (stageY > 0) {
        stage.setY(stageY);
    }
}
```

But if I move the mouse too fast, the mouse pointer is moved in the scene and so the result is not correct.

where am I wrong?

Comment: What does the following mean? => "the mouse pointer is moved in the scene and so the result is not correct".  You might want to supply an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody could replicate this (probably just plain code without FXML as FXML use is unlikely to be core to your issue).

Comment: I seem to have a performance problem. When I move my mouse for drag the panel in a steady way, not ridicously fast, I notice the panel is always drawn a few centimeters behind on the mouse trail, and only catches up when I stop moving the cursor. This in a scenegraph with only a handful nodes.

Comment: If I don't perform any check on the stage position, it is fluid without any performance problem.

Comment: This. Wish I knew how to code the default high performance implementation of window drag.